# n:m table to connect two tables OR one field that contains "comma" seperated values

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello my question is which approach makes more sense. I don't like the "comma separated values in a field" approach... but I'm not sure which approach is better for getting good performance.

My table contains different values that "depend" on the previous value to give a clear structure. (e.g. **Column A** has **Column B** which is used as **Column C** for **Column D**(does it make sense?^^))

my table with a lot of duplicates:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BB | YYY | RRR |
| AA | BB | XXX | RRR |
| AA | BB | ZZZ | RRR |

reduced to:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BB | YYY,XXX,ZZZ | RRR |

It is also possible that I need a fifth and sixth column with different values and then this "matrix" will grow up...

my other "problem" is that, **Column A has Column C** is **not logically** because **the part "Column B" of Column A has Column C**

Comment: Whatever you choose as "solution" to the problem, don't store comma-separated values into a single column.

Comment: ok, that was my guess. Then I should accept a rather a lot of duplicates?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't think I understand the meaning of "column X *_has*_ column Y".  Can you rewrite or expand your description using the phrase "depends on"?

Comment: Ok, a plant has a leaf and I can use this leaf for xxx

Comment: Explaining the business problem might make it clearer.  From your description, I would be suspicious that you actually want more than one junction table.  n:m mapping tables with 4 or 6 separate keys would be unusual.

Comment: Comma-separated will almost always require more coding, more debugging, will be more error prone, and less performant.

Comment: Comma-separated violates the very first rule of relational data design, AKA "First Normal Form".

Comment: Ok, let me explain, here's what I want to say. The Anagalis arvensis plant has various tissues such as leaves and roots. I can use the root to use as a pain reliever to cure my headache and the root has an active ingredient and one or more effects. So i have this fields: plant, (with) tissue,(as) usages, (for different) "illness", (the tissue has several) active ingedrient, (with different depending) effects

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I think the main thing you want to know is that a relation between three entities can, like ones between two of them, be modeled by a linking table.

So let's start with the base tables.

```
-- all the plants
CREATE TABLE plant
             (id integer,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

-- all the tissues a (any) plant can have
CREATE TABLE tissue
             (id integer,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

-- all the ingredients
CREATE TABLE ingredient
             (id integer,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

-- all the illnesses
CREATE TABLE illness
             (id integer,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

-- all the effects
CREATE TABLE effect
             (id integer,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Then continue with the binary linking tables.

```
-- which ingredient causes which effect?
CREATE TABLE ingredient_effect
             (ingredient integer,
              effect integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (ingredient,
                           effect),
              FOREIGN KEY (ingredient)
                          REFERENCES ingredient
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (effect)
                          REFERENCES effect
                                     (id));

-- which effect helps against which illness?
CREATE TABLE illness_effect
             (illness integer,
              effect integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (illness,
                           effect),
              FOREIGN KEY (illness)
                          REFERENCES illness
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (effect)
                          REFERENCES effect
                                     (id));
```

And finally the ternary linking table.

```
-- which ingredient can be found in which tissue of which plant?
CREATE TABLE plant_tissue_ingredient
             (plant integer,
              tissue integer,
              ingredient integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (plant,
                           tissue,
                           ingredient),
              FOREIGN KEY (plant)
                          REFERENCES plant
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (tissue)
                          REFERENCES tissue
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (ingredient)
                          REFERENCES ingredient
                                     (id));
```

Comment: Thank you, yes you are right. Of course I forgot to mention the most important thing... my datasets are not complete, Sometimes I only know plants, tissues and effects. (Ingredient is unknown) In addition, each use and disease is plant-specific and cannot be generalized at this time. So I cannot say that use -> is disease because the use of the plant can be used for the specific disease.I'm sorry I forgot this last night... I think unfortunately I cannot implement your proposed structure at the moment. Maybe i should use a linking table referenced primary key? e.g. PLA_ID & TISSUE_ID has a pk?

Comment: And yes, I can link plants, tissues and effects, but later I have to restructure the entire database, otherwise this is not logical?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested table:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list As TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);

CREATE TABLE table_name (
  colA VARCHAR2(20),
  colB VARCHAR2(20),
  colC string_list,
  colD VARCHAR2(20)
) NESTED TABLE colC STORE AS table_name__colc;

INSERT INTO table_name (
  colA, colB, colC, colD
) VALUES (
  'AAA', 'BBB', string_list( 'YYY', 'XXX', 'ZZZ' ), 'RRR'
);
```

Or, you can just use a second table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name2 (
  id   NUMBER
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
       PRIMARY KEY,
  colA VARCHAR2(20),
  colB VARCHAR2(20),
  colD VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE table_name2c (
  id    NUMBER
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
        PRIMARY KEY,
  tn_id NUMBER
        REFERENCES table_name2( id ),
  colC VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO table_name2 (
  colA, colB, colD
) VALUES (
  'AAA', 'BBB', 'RRR'
);

INSERT INTO table_name2c ( tn_id, colC )
SELECT 1, 'YYY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'XXX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'ZZZ' FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of my incomplete data and to cover all cases, I have now come to the following tables. (using the example of sticky bit).

Feedback would be terrific :)

**temporary:**

- plant_ingredient
- plant_effect
- plant_illness
- plant_tissue
- plant_usage
- plant_tissue_usage_ingredient_effect
- (plant_tissue_effect)
- (plant_usage_illness)
- (plant_tissue_illness)
- (plant_tissue_usage)
- (plant_usage_effect)

**logical:**

- ingredient_effect
- plant_tissue_ingredient
- plant_tissue_usage_illness
- (plant_tissue_usage_effect)